# Programmatically add button based on existing layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011092/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-button-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) , it is possible to programmatically add button in java.

I would like to build my buttons based on a layout. Is it possible ?

For example,

```xml
<!-- btn.xml-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:onClick="myFunction"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

In my java code, I build buttons over a `String list` like this :

```java
final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
for(String label : stringList){
    Log.d("BTN_ITERATION", "for label : " + label);
    Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn.setText(label);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```

For each button iteration, I'd like to set a `btn.xml` layout.

I thought about something like this but I don't know :

```java
button = (button) View.inflate(this, R.layout.btn, null);
layout.addView(button);
```

Thanks ! ;)

Comment: please try your suggestion and if your face errors then you can ask question with more precession. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this similar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429255/create-android-buttons-programmatically-using-xml-layout-as-template).

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.btn, layout, false);
```

Comment: Your link is very useful, it solved my "problem". Other great document [here](https://medium.com/@pranitsawant01/about-androids-layoutinflater-inflate-5188a247c8fc) ! Thank you ! ;)